# GestureOverlay Stroke thickness and redraw duration with android

Tags: android, gestureoverlayview

I am using `GestureOverlayView` to capture the user signature in my android application. Below is the `xml`:

```
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
        android:id="@+id/signaturePad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_90sdp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblAuthorize"
        android:background="@drawable/signature_background"
        android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true"
        android:fadeEnabled="false"
        android:gestureColor="#0e40e6"
        android:gestureStrokeLengthThreshold="0.1"
        android:gestureStrokeAngleThreshold="0.1"
        android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
```

- Are there anyways I can reduce the thickness of the stroke? It has some default thickness of some `5dp`? I need to make it more thinner. I just browsed through all the Sites but did not found any relevant resources or options for this
- Are there anyways, I can stop the `GestureOverlayView` getting cleared after around 2-3 secs, seems like default behavior though?

Comment: read `android.gesture.GestureOverlayView` documentation, there you have the answers for your questions